# Oracle APEX installed on Container database and configure to use pluaggable database

Tags: oracle, configuration, oracle-apex, oracle19c

I have installed Oracle APEX 22.1 on Oracle Database 19c Container database. In database I have 11 pluggable database. Now I want to access that PDB from oracle apex configured environment.

How can I do that?

Kindly help with any link

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just look into the PDBs like that. In general, APEX or any other application code should never be installed in the CDB. The CDB should only be used to manage the PDBs.